# How to remove NavLink styling for unselected Routes

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to know how to restore to the default style of NavLink as marked in the screenshot below. The `color` should be white and without the underlines. You would find my code below the screenshot:
Home is the default path that is currently selected. The activeClass property on this is working as it should.

[image]

The code:

```
const NavBar = () => {
    return(
        <div className="navBar">
            <div className="logo">LOGO</div>
            <div className="navOptions">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink exact activeClassName="activeClass" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink exact activeClassName="activeClass" to="/advanceFilter">Advanced Search</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <NavLink exact activeClassName="activeClass" to="viewAll">View All</NavLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>Logout</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

The CSS:

```
.navBar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.navOptions {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

//The li items don't have the color and text-decoration properties on them
li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}

ul {
    margin-right: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.activeClass {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: purple;
}
```

Comment: `NavLink` elements accept a `className` property alongside the `activeClassName` property, and compile to an `a` tag - you can add your styling onto the `a` element or add a custom class via `className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NavLink` component renders an anchor `<a />` tag, update the selector in your CSS to also target anchor tags that are children of `li` elements.

```
li, li a {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could also specify a "navlink" class and apply default non-active CSS styling there.